# How to show stored pdf btye array in SQL Server to asp.net WebForm in a image box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-ajax

i am developing a web application in that i need to store image files and some other documents in a database and then i have to show them on a web page in an image box preferably. i have stored images in database and also PDF files in the form of byte array and i used a Generic Handler to get byte array  from database and then show them in a image box it works fine for the images but it does not work with PDF files.

```
public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    { 
        Int32 imgID;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            imgID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        byte[] buffer = ShowEmpImage(imgID);
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }

    public Stream ShowEmpImage(int empno)
    {
        dbClass db = new dbClass();
        string sql = "SELECT imgfile FROM myFiles WHERE id = @ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, db.con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", empno);
        object img = null;
        try
        {
            db.Connect();
            img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Disconnect();
        }
        return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

please guide me how can i show PDF files and some other files to the image box? actually the problem is my application runs with the existing application and that have no way to store extensions of files so the only way i can show files is "show them in as a image" but if their is a better way then help me out friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason that PDF doesn't work when representing it as an image... *it isn't an image*. Additionally, claiming it is `"image/jpeg"` is going to make it pretty broken unless the browser does explicit file-header checking, and really need fixing IMO. If you don't currently store the file name / extension / MIME / something then frankly: that's a problem you need to fix.

For displaying a PDF, I suspect you'd need to use an `<iframe>` rather than an `<img>`, which a: might not work on all browsers, and b: might not be very convenient to the caller. Personally I'd just offer a download link (and in the handler, use `content-disposition` to tell the browser to treat it as a download).

Comment: so tell me how can i display it with out browser limitation? i need to show both image files or PDF files on my webpage, whats a better way to display them on web page?

Comment: @AqEeL if you want to display an *image* of the PDF, perhaps [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255322/create-pdf-thumbnail-with-c-sharp). Otherwise; use an `<iframe>` and hope for the best

Comment: thanks for your help but it did not work for my scenario. if you have any knowledge of more specific then tell me i shall be thankful

Comment: @AqEeL there isn't a specific question, so it is hard to give a specific answer. But "don't try and display a PDF in a `<img>` tag - that won't work" feels pretty specific... if you mean you are using an `<iframe>` but haven't changed the content-type, then again: "don't claim something is a jpeg, but send pdf - that won't work" feels pretty specific...

Comment: at the end of the day i have done this. thanks for your guidence

Comment: hey @Marc Gravell now i have done displaying images and pdfs on web page without storing their extensions in database. and of-course i used iframe for this.

Comment: hi @Marc Gravell i need your help. for this application i saved and retrieve images in and from SQL Server2008, but my application crashes when i upload more than 4MB file i need to upload file with larger size how can i do this? how to allow user to upload files of large size like in more than 100MB or 500MB or more than a 1GB. its urgent for me.

Comment: @AqEeL first, define "crashes". Second, consider whether a RDBMS is really the best place for such a big file (well, `FileStream` is a halfway hybrid). Third, for the download: check you are using streaming techniques - i.e. looping with a buffer and telling the db access to use sequential access; **not** regular "give me the data**. Fourth - for upload.... is this server-to-server? or browser-to-server? for browser-to-server, you'll be lucky to make that work for files that big; FTP is more suitable at that size.

Comment: @AqEeL checking the code, yes: you'll NEVER make that work with anything involving `ExecuteScalar`, `MemoryStream` or `byte[]`. You need to use `ExecuteReader` with the sequential flag (`CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`), using `ReadBytes` in a loop, i.e. create a smallish buffer (maybe 8k); read a buffer of data; write that buffer to the response; repeat (re-using the same buffer each time). You **cannot** load that data into memory all at once.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Marc Gravell
when i choose file and click on a button to upload i goes a page like visual studio is closed and i want to run my project. some thing like that.
here is my code that i am using to save PDF and image files.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO uploadedfiles(name, srID, policy, date, LOGpdf, fileExtension) VALUES(@p, @d, @pol, @dt, @img, @extension) SELECT @@IDENTITY";

                db.Connect();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, db.con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", txtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", txtSrID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pol", lblPolicyID.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", txtDate.Text);
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", imgByte);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extension", extension);
                }
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

i was searching and discussing with my friend and we come up with this, code and this help me but my friend said that it will only upload files upto 100MB.

```
<location path="UploadFiles.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="2040" maxRequestLength="104857600"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

And in my application might be user want to upload files having size more than 100MB in that case this will also crash.